# Get current foreground App process name does not work in API level 22 in Android

Tags: android

I have been using this function in my code to get the current foreground app name(package name i.e ). Somehow this code does not return the app name for android 5.1 which happens to be API level 22. RunningAppProcessInfo does not seem deprecated or anything. So I'm wondering as to why this code fails for 5.1(API level 22).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = ((ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    appName = appProcess.processName;
                    Log.d("Android App Name",appName);
                    break;
                }
```

The android I am running my code on is 5.1. Any pointers will help. Thanks in advance.